# Change Total with a click of the button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<button id "add" onclick="changeTotal()">change total add 5</button>
<button id "subtract" onclick="changeTotal()">change total subtract 5</button>


var Total = 10;

function changeTotal () {

if (add === true) {

   total = total + 5;
} else (subtract === true) {
 total = total - 5;
};
```

I am not sure how the heck to accomplish this...newbie...but I want to have two buttons.  One that adds to my total in

...and another button that subtracts to my total in

.  I need it to be ongoing...like not stop at a certain number -negative or +positive.  Thanks all!

I tried screwing around with my newly learned knowledge of innerHTML...

```
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>

<button onclick="displayTotal()">The time is?</button>

<script>
function displayTotal() {

   var x = 5;
   var p = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = + 5;


}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you just want the `div` to increment every time you click the button, rather than continuously increment after one click.

```
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>

<button onclick="displayTotal();">The time is?</button>

<script>
function displayTotal() {
   var p = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(p, 10) + 5;
}
</script>

<p id="demo">0</p>
```

If you want two buttons that will increment or decrement, you can just parameterize the function.

```
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>

<button onclick="increment(5);">Increment</button>
<button onclick="increment(-5);">Decrement</button>

<script>
function increment(val) {
   var p = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(p, 10) + val;
}
</script>

<p id="demo">0</p>
```

Comment: So how would you save/store the number the you end up with?  Lets say i want it to be 50 points this week, then later i could add 5 or ten the next week the the number that was last saved.

Comment: @Dlaugh14, That is technically an unrelated question, and will require more context (such as which server-side language and storage scheme you plan to use). Please read up on server-side languages such as `PHP` and `ASP.NET`, try a few things, and then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/GbGT2/)'s a demo. Don't worry about the event listeners: you can just use the `onclick` a, but JSFiddle doesn't like those. The basic concept is that you want a `div` to hold the value and you want to store that value in your JS file, changing it and setting the `div` to the new value each time.

Comment: So how would you save/store the number the you end up with?  Lets say i want it to be 50 points this week, then later i could add 5 or ten the next week the the number that was last saved.

Comment: In this case, it would be stored in the `total` variable.